# My code get data from database using AJAX and return to view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

My code get data from database using AJAX the problem is i want to filter data by month year and quarter and the code that does that is:

```
->where(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->month);
```

However can't put it in a variable for example and call it so i did this it works but looks ugly.

I have this code in `DashboardController`:

```
public function readData(){

$TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
    ->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
    ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
    ->select(
       'users.name as name',
       'group_user.user_id as id',
       'groups.name as groupname'
       )
    ->get();

    $filter = $_REQUEST["filter"]; // Get the variable data through AJAX call from the index


    foreach ($TableB1 as &$entry){
        if ($filter == 'month'){ // Filter data by month
        $meetings = \DB::table('meetings') 
        ->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $entry->id) 
        ->where(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->month);
        }
        else if ($filter == 'quarter'){ // Filter data by quarter
            $meetings = \DB::table('meetings') 
            ->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $entry->id) 
            ->where(\DB::raw('QUARTER(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->quarter);
        }
        else if ($filter == 'year'){ // Filter data by year
            $meetings = \DB::table('meetings') 
            ->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $entry->id) 
            ->where(\DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->year);
        } else { // Filter data by day
            $meetings = \DB::table('meetings') 
            ->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $entry->id) 
            ->where(\DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->day);
        }
        $entry->meetingsCount = $meetings->count();


    }

    return $TableB1;

 }
```

In `index.blade.php` I have this code to retrieve the data using ajax:

```
var filter = 'day';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/dashboard/read?filter=' + filter, function(data){
        $.each(data,function(i,value){
            var tr =$("<tr/>");
            tr.append($("<th/>",{
                text : value.groupname
            })).append($("<th/>",{
                text : value.name
            })).append($("<th/>",{
                text : value.meetingsCount
            })).append($("<th/>",{
                text : value.callsCount
            })).append($("<th/>",{
                text : value.leadsCount
            }))
            $('#tableData').append(tr);
        })
    })

    $("#day").click(function() { // Filter data by day
        filter = 'day';

        $('#tableData').find('tr').empty(); // Clear Table 1st


        $.get('/dashboard/read?filter=' + filter, function(data){
            $.each(data,function(i,value){
                var tr =$("<tr/>");
                tr.append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.groupname
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.name
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.meetingsCount
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.callsCount
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.leadsCount
                }))
                $('#tableData').append(tr);
            })
        })
    });

    $("#month").click(function() { //Filter data by month
        $('#tableData').find('tr').empty(); // Clear Table 1st

        filter = 'month';

        $.get('/dashboard/read?filter=' + filter, function(data){
            $.each(data,function(i,value){
                var tr =$("<tr/>");
                tr.append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.groupname
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.name
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.meetingsCount
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.callsCount
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.leadsCount
                }))
                $('#tableData').append(tr);
            })
        })
    });

    $("#quarter").click(function() { //Filter data by quarter
        filter = 'quarter';

        $('#tableData').find('tr').empty(); // Clear Table 1st

        $.get('/dashboard/read?filter=' + filter, function(data){
            $.each(data,function(i,value){
                var tr =$("<tr/>");
                tr.append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.groupname
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.name
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.meetingsCount
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.callsCount
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.leadsCount
                }))
                $('#tableData').append(tr);
            })
        })
    });

    $("#year").click(function() { //Filter data by year
        filter = 'year';

        $('#tableData').find('tr').empty(); // Clear Table 1st

        $.get('/dashboard/read?filter=' + filter, function(data){
            $.each(data,function(i,value){
                var tr =$("<tr/>");
                tr.append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.groupname
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.name
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.meetingsCount
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.callsCount
                })).append($("<th/>",{
                    text : value.leadsCount
                }))
                $('#tableData').append(tr);
            })
        })
    });
```

I know its a mess but how to refactor this code to make it look a little bit nicer the code works but looks awful.

Comment: Do you have Eloquent models set up for your tables i.e. `User` and `Group`?

Comment: No i don't have Eloquent for them

Comment: @user194899 Are you opposed to using Eloquent in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use php's super globals with Laravel. For the most part you can use the [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests) class for this. With most things in Laravel, the `Request` can be accessed in multiple different ways including [injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers) (where it is resolved from the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#resolving)), [facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/facades) and [helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-request). For this example I'll use the request helper function:

```
$filter = request()->input('filter');
```

*You could also do `request('filter')` but for some params this could cause an issue.

---

As for you query I would strongly recommend using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) instead of the query builder in this case.

You should already have a `User` model in your app directory so you should just need to create the `Group` and `Meeting` models. You can run the following command to do this:

```
php artisan make:model Group && php artisan make:model Meeting
```

Then add the following to your `User` model:

```
public function meetings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Meeting::class, 'owned_by_id');
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

and add the following to your `Group` model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

finally, you don't need to do this yet but in your `Meeting` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'owned_by_id');
}
```

---

The above will allow you to have a controller method looking something like:

```
public function readData()
{
    $filter = request()->input('filter');

    return \App\User::with('groups')->withCount(['meetings' => function ($query) use ($filter) {

        $filter = in_array($filter, ['month', 'quarter', 'year']) ? $filter : 'day';

        $query->where('company_id', 1)->whereRaw("$filter(created_at)", today()->$filter);
    }]);
}
```

`groupname` will now be available as `group->name` and the count will be available as `meetings_count`.